# Button в форме отправляет её

Tags: button, javascript, ajax, form

Здравствуйте

Пишу сайт, очень плотно используя ajax. Наткнулся на проблему в неожиданном месте.

Есть вот такой элемент:

```
<form class='columns set'>
                    <input name='id' type='hidden' value='".$id."'>

                    <div>
                        <input name='name' type='text' value='Газовые гарелки'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='options'>
                        <button class='radial s hamburger dark' action='open setFields'><hr><hr><hr></button>
                        <button class='radial s cross dark'><hr><hr></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Обработчик кликов вот такой:

```
d.body.addEventListener("click", function(e){

    var target = e.target;

    do{
        if(target.tagName == "BUTTON") {

            var action = target.getAttribute('action');

            if(action == "open setFields"){
                setsFields.open(target);

            }

            break;
        }
    }while(target = target.parentNode);

}, false);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на кнопку внутри form перезагружается страница.
Не понимаю, почему это происходит. Насколько я знаю, для отправки формы нужен `<input type='submit'>`, а `, false);` предотвращает действие браузера по умолчанию.

Объясните, пожалуйста, где я неправ и как дальше жить!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Решение](http://jsfiddle.net/jpLoyf09/). Все просто - третий параметр не предотвращает действие браузера по умолчанию. От него зависит, как будет обрабатываться события - bubling или capturing. Подробнее почитать можно [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126471/). Предотвращает действие по умолчанию метод `preventDefault()` у `event`'a.

Answer (score 0):

button - это по умолчанию **input[type="submit"]**, для самого простого обхода проблемы добавьте тегу *<button>* свойство **type="button"**

Comment: А возможно ли как-то по умолчанию установит type="button", чтобы не приходилось писать это в каждой кнопке?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, `<button>`